# Google Maps Javascript API, MarkerWithLabel z-index

Tags: google-maps

First time poster, long time listener.

I am developing a Google Maps application and am using MarkerWithLabel to display the number of parking spots available in various parking lots around our town.

The z-index of the MarkerWithLabel appears to be messed up and no matter what I do to change z-indexes nothing seems to help.

As you can see from the screen shot.

From what I can ascertain (via developer tools in Chrome) is that the (P) icon has a z-index of 1, the label also has a z-index of 1 and the current position marker has a z-index of 10000. So I am unsure why the current position marker sits underneath the label but yet on top of the (P) icon.

Ideally I want the current position icon (in red) to sit over top of both the label and the (P) icons.

[image: my problem]

Can anyone help me with how z-indexes work with the Google Maps Javascript API as I am obviously missing something here.